# "Unknown layer: Lambda" in tensorflowjs on browser

Tags: python, tensorflow.js

I am new in machine learning area. i am trying to run python program on browser by converting trained model in tensorflow js.

[this attention_ocr](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/attention_ocr/python) is related to OCR written in python. i have generated HDF5/H5 file and converted that in web specific format with `tensorflowjs_converter`[[ref]](https://js.tensorflow.org/tutorials/import-keras.html).

I follow all instruction given in [this](https://js.tensorflow.org/tutorials/import-keras.html) document but at the time of running in browser it throwing me error *(refer screenshot)*

[image]

> I am looking for solution to remove this error...!

**Referance :**

[tensorflow.org](https://js.tensorflow.org/tutorials/)

[How to import a TensorFlow SavedModel into TensorFlow.js](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-converter)

[Importing a Keras model into TensorFlow.js](https://js.tensorflow.org/tutorials/import-keras.html)

Comment: Try upgrading to the latest tf.js version (0.11.6). If it still doesn't work, your saved model is using a Lamba layer, which isn't implemented in tfjs yet.

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel , having same error with tf.js version (0.11.6)...!

Answer (score 3):

Lambda (native code) layers are not supported in TensorFlow.js.  You will need to replace it with a custom layer.  This is tricky.  Here is an example custom layer: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-examples/tree/master/custom-layer

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a custom layer class as @BlessedKey stated above (https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-examples/tree/master/custom-layer).

You also have to edit the model.json file. The model definition must be updated point to the new class you created for your custom layer instead of the Lambda class. Find the lambda layer inside your model.json and change the "class_name": "Lambda" attribute to "class_name": "YourCustomLayer". You can find an example here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/283.

Also make sure to return the correct tensor shape from `computeOutputShape(inputShape)` or you'll get bothered by this pesky guy:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'dtype' of undefined
at executor.js:29
at t.e.add (executor.js:96)
at SA (executor.js:341)
at training.js:1063
at engine.js:425
at t.e.scopedRun (engine.js:436)
at t.e.tidy (engine.js:423)
at Nb (globals.js:182)
at s (training.js:1046)
at training.js:1045
```