# Alternative for Lambda layer in yolo3 Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow.js, yolo

*My Goal*

I want to train a custom object detection model in Tensorflow(python) and use it using Tensorflow js after digging lot of example I found [this](https://github.com/qqwweee/keras-yolo3/blob/master/train.py) which is widely popular

*What I have done*

I have written ( taken help form online examples ) the Tensorflow JS  part to load a model from local and get the get the predictions. I used with COCO pretrained model It is working fine (so not adding the code here).

*What is my problem*

I am very new to python and Tensorflow. 
The example for training [qqwweee/keras-yolo3](https://github.com/qqwweee/keras-yolo3/blob/master/train.py) the model is in python and it is Lamda from Keras

`from keras.layers import Input, Lambda` for this places

```
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-3), loss={
# use custom yolo_loss Lambda layer.
'yolo_loss': lambda y_true, y_pred: y_pred})
```

And

```
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-4), loss={'yolo_loss': lambda y_true, y_pred: y_pred}) # recompile to apply the change
```

And

```
model_loss = Lambda(yolo_loss, output_shape=(1,), name='yolo_loss',
    arguments={'anchors': anchors, 'num_classes': num_classes, 'ignore_thresh': 0.5})(
    [*model_body.output, *y_true])
model = Model([model_body.input, *y_true], model_loss)
```

So What I understood so far, Lambda is mainly used for calculating the loss function, and this is causing main problem in TFJS because Lambda layer is not implemented till now I want to use some alternative instead of lambda layer.
This is the error I am getting while using the trained model in TFJS

```
Error loading layer ValueError: Unknown layer: Lambda. This may be due to one of the following reasons:
1. The layer is defined in Python, in which case it needs to be ported to TensorFlow.js or your JavaScript code.
2. The custom layer is defined in JavaScript, but is not registered properly with tf.serialization.registerClass().
```

Similar question is also asked here ["Unknown layer: Lambda" in tensorflowjs on browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50878885/unknown-layer-lambda-in-tensorflowjs-on-browser), it talks about writing a custom layer , the example is not enough to do that, ultimately leads to dead end.

*What I want*

1. Is there any way to use any other loss function insteed of lambda ? how?
2. Is there any example for writing custom layer for lambda
3. Where are my understanding are wrong?

p.s: I spent hell lot of time to find the solution, any help will be appreciated, Thanks in advance

---

After adding the empty lambda layer given by @edkeveked (Thanks!), the error `Error loading layer ValueError: Unknown layer: Lambda` is gone but ran into something else.

Check the model summary [here](https://pastebin.com/Gwza9sZy)

Now, In the model warmup itslef thorowing this error 
code for warmup

```
let zero = tfNode.zeros([1, 416, 416, 3]);
const result = await this.model.predict(zero)
result.map(async (t) => await t.data());
result.map(async (t) => t.dispose());
```

code for image prediction

```
batched = tfNode.tidy(() => {
    if (!(img instanceof tfNode.Tensor)) {
        img = tfNode.browser.fromPixels(img);
    }
    return img.expandDims(0);
});
result = await this.model.predict(batched);
```

Error I am getting

```
"Error: Error when checking model : the Array of Tensors that you are passing to your model is not the size the the model expected. Expected to see 4 Tensor(s), but instead got 1 Tensors(s).
    at new ValueError (XXX\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-layers\dist\errors.js:68:28)
    at checkInputData (XXX\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-layers\dist\engine\training.js:316:19)
    at LayersModel.predict (XXX\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-layers\dist\engine\training.js:981:9)
    at ObjectDetection.warmUp (XXX\tensorflow_predownloaded_model.js:47:45)
    at XXX\tensorflow_predownloaded_model.js:38:18"
```

Comment: Maybe you would need to register your own class. What is the yolo loss doing ?

Comment: Not totally understood, but it is doing many thing this is the code https://github.com/qqwweee/keras-yolo3/blob/e6598d13c703029b2686bc2eb8d5c09badf42992/yolo3/model.py#L345

Comment: Here is an example of how to register customized layers: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-examples/tree/master/custom-layer

Answer (score 2):

Since the Lambda layer is not yet supported, it need to be provided for the conversion to work. 
Moreover, the loaded layer is not used for training, so the lambda layer can be empty. (code not tried)

```
class Lambda extends tf.layers.Layer {
  constructor() {
    super({})
  }

  static get className() {
    return 'Lambda';
  }

}

tf.serialization.SerializationMap.register(Lambda);
```

;

Comment: Thanks! I have added  the layer, the `unknown layer lambda error` is gone now but it not able to figure out what it is expecting in the predict function, I have updated my question can you please check once. Thank you again

Comment: I initially thought that the lambda layer was only use for the loss function. But it is not. The loss function is calculated using a layer `yolo_loss` on which a Lambda layer is applied. Looking at the error it seems that the layer should return an array of 4 tensors. If you can do a google colab with both your python and the js code, I could review it easily. To help you start, here is a colab I wrote for a lambda layer: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1I3puy6Ya4_q2oslhwuayrgjk5fKichY7