# How to train a custom Object detector from scratch in tensorflow.js?

Tags: tensorflow.js

I followed multiple example, to train a custom object detector in TensorflowJS . The main problem I am facing every where it is using pretrained model.

Pretrained models are fine for general use cases, but custom scenario it fails. For example, [take this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-examples/tree/master/simple-object-detection) this is example form official Tensorflowjs examples, here it is  using mobilenet, and mobilenet and mobilenet has image size restriction 224x224 which defeats all the purpose, because my images are big and also not of same ratio so resizing is not an option.

I have tried multiple example, all follows same path oneway or another.

What I want ?
Any example by which I can train a custom objector from scratch in Tensorflow.js.

Although the answer sounds simple but trust me I searching for this for multiple days. Any help will be greatly  appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Currently it is not yet possible to use tensorflow object detection api in nodejs. But the image size should not be a restriction. Maybe instead of resizing, you can crop your image and keep only the part that contain your object to be detected

Comment: omg! didn't know that, I am sad now :(, so corping will be a huge trouble, think you have 720x1080 image now how you corp. that image? One approach will be like partition the image in 224x224 and run for all partitions  but  what if the object is between two partitions, does using phython tensorflow helps?

Answer (score 2):

Currently it is not yet possible to use tensorflow object detection api in nodejs. But the image size should not be a restriction. Instead of resizing, you can crop your image and keep only the part that contain your object to be detected.

> One approach will be like partition the image in 224x224 and run for all partitions but what if the object is between two partitions

The image does not need to be partitioned for it. When labelling the image, you will need to know the x, y coordinates (from the top left) and the w, h of the detected box. You only need to crop a part of the image that will contain the box. Cropping at the coordinates `x - (224-w)/2, y- (224-h)/2` can be a good start. There are two issues with these coordinates:

- the detected boxes will always be in the center, so the training will be biaised. To prevent it, a randomn factor can be used. `x - (224-w)/r , y- (224-h)/r` where r can be randomly taken from [1-10] for instance
- if the detected boxes are bigger than `224 * 224` maybe you might first choose to resize the video keeping it ratio before cropping. In this case the boxe size (w, h) will need to be readjusted according to the scale used for the resizing

Comment: Hi @edkeveked thanks for the answer, for training I have understood the training part, but now consider, after training,  I have a Image of 1024x720 and now I want to detect objects in it now in which logic I will corp, what if while corping the object falls in the partition line?

Comment: For inference, you will only need to resize to 224* 224. You will get the detected box in that image and after you scale it back to 1024*720. But if you want to train with the image 1024*720, you can consider using a FC model from original size to 224 * 224, then use a mobilenet and a FC to predict the bounding box. The training will take much longer. I haven't tried it to tell if it will give more accurate results

Comment: I will give it a try, but it will distort  the objects in the image for mismatch ratio, and in training it has never seen this kind of image, not very sure how it will perform, will it be a better Idea to train from scratch in python and infer by tfjs?

Comment: If you have the possibility to train in python, I think you will have more possibility than in js for now. And after you can import the saved model

Comment: that's what I am planing to do now AGAIN, I already followed that path, faced several issue then I came back here (tfjs). I faced several issue there as well, This is where I gave up in TF python check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59233377/alternative-for-lambda-layer-in-yolo3-keras