# Tensorflow.js Error: Unknown layer: Functional

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I'm loading a simple Tensorflow.js model using `tf.loadLayersModel()`, but the model is not building. I am using the Functional API to build the Model, but only consisting of Dense Layers. A similar error [seems to arise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50878885/unknown-layer-lambda-in-tensorflowjs-on-browser/50893452#50893452) with Lambda layers, but I only use 2 Dense Layers and functional layers [are supported](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/guide/models_and_layers#the_functional_model) in Tf.js.

**Full Error:**

```
Error: Unknown layer: Functional. This may be due to one of the following reasons:
1. The layer is defined in Python, in which case it needs to be ported to TensorFlow.js or your JavaScript code.
2. The custom layer is defined in JavaScript, but is not registered properly with tf.serialization.registerClass()
```

**The JS code that triggers it:**

```
const http = tf.io.http

tf.loadLayersModel(http(url)).then((model) => {
    console.log('Loaded model.')
    console.log(model)
})
```

**`url`'s fetched content (aka the `model.json` file)**

```
{"format": "layers-model", "generatedBy": "keras v2.4.0", "convertedBy": "TensorFlow.js Converter v2.0.1.post1", "modelTopology": {"keras_version": "2.4.0", "backend": "tensorflow", "model_config": {"class_name": "Functional", "config": {"name": "my_model", "layers": [{"class_name": "InputLayer", "config": {"batch_input_shape": [null, 10], "dtype": "float32", "sparse": false, "ragged": false, "name": "input_1"}, "name": "input_1", "inbound_nodes": []}, {"class_name": "Dense", "config": {"name": "dense", "trainable": true, "dtype": "float32", "units": 20, "activation": "relu", "use_bias": true, "kernel_initializer": {"class_name": "GlorotUniform", "config": {"seed": null}}, "bias_initializer": {"class_name": "Zeros", "config": {}}, "kernel_regularizer": null, "bias_regularizer": null, "activity_regularizer": null, "kernel_constraint": null, "bias_constraint": null}, "name": "dense", "inbound_nodes": [[["input_1", 0, 0, {}]]]}, {"class_name": "Dense", "config": {"name": "dense_1", "trainable": true, "dtype": "float32", "units": 20, "activation": "relu", "use_bias": true, "kernel_initializer": {"class_name": "GlorotUniform", "config": {"seed": null}}, "bias_initializer": {"class_name": "Zeros", "config": {}}, "kernel_regularizer": null, "bias_regularizer": null, "activity_regularizer": null, "kernel_constraint": null, "bias_constraint": null}, "name": "dense_1", "inbound_nodes": [[["dense", 0, 0, {}]]]}, {"class_name": "Dense", "config": {"name": "dense_2", "trainable": true, "dtype": "float32", "units": 10, "activation": "linear", "use_bias": true, "kernel_initializer": {"class_name": "GlorotUniform", "config": {"seed": null}}, "bias_initializer": {"class_name": "Zeros", "config": {}}, "kernel_regularizer": null, "bias_regularizer": null, "activity_regularizer": null, "kernel_constraint": null, "bias_constraint": null}, "name": "dense_2", "inbound_nodes": [[["dense_1", 0, 0, {}]]]}], "input_layers": [["input_1", 0, 0]], "output_layers": [["dense_2", 0, 0]]}}, "training_config": {"loss": "mse", "metrics": "accuracy", "weighted_metrics": null, "loss_weights": null, "optimizer_config": {"class_name": "RMSprop", "config": {"name": "RMSprop", "learning_rate": 0.001, "decay": 0.0, "rho": 0.9, "momentum": 0.0, "epsilon": 1e-07, "centered": false}}}}, "weightsManifest": [{"paths": ["group1-shard1of1.bin"], "weights": [{"name": "dense/kernel", "shape": [10, 20], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "dense/bias", "shape": [20], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "dense_1/kernel", "shape": [20, 20], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "dense_1/bias", "shape": [20], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "dense_2/kernel", "shape": [20, 10], "dtype": "float32"}, {"name": "dense_2/bias", "shape": [10], "dtype": "float32"}]}]}
```

**Want to reproduce the model? Here's the python code:**

```
import keras
import keras.layers as layers
import tensorflowjs as tfjs

inputs = keras.Input(shape=(10,))
dense = layers.Dense(20, activation="relu")
x = dense(inputs)
x = layers.Dense(20, activation="relu")(x)
outputs = layers.Dense(10)(x)

# Create the model
model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name="my_model")

KEY = 'sampleid'
MDL = 'mymodel'

model.compile(loss='mse',metrics='accuracy')

tfjs.converters.save_keras_model(model, MDL)
```

**NOTE:**
The URL is a bit verbose (it's a Firebase Storage downloadURL) and I'm not confident the IOHandler (`http`) can parse the `weightPathPrefix` perfectly. I am not sure this is *the* issue or even *an* issue, but it could create problems if it was incorrect and I don't know how to check it's calculated value.

**Versions:**

```
JS:  Tensorflow.js : 2.0.1
Py:  Tensorflowjs  : 2.0.1.post1
Py:  Keras         : 2.4.3
```

### Update 7/29/20:

The issue seems to be in the parsing of the model weights (see NOTE). I added this example to a [GitHub ticket](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/3631#issuecomment-665639995) about the `tf.loadLayersModel()` function earlier, which contains a lot of details about attempted solutions.

Comment: what version of tensorflow are you using ?

Comment: 2.0.1 @edkeveked

Comment: I am able to convert and load your model. I am using tf.tensorflow package rather than keras. Here are my imports: `import tensorflow.keras as keras
import tensorflow.keras.layers as layers`

Comment: @edkeveked I was able to as well from Python's `tfjs` using `tfjs.converters.load_keras_model()`, but not Tensorflow.js' `loadLayersModel()`,which  is the environment I'm looking to make predictions in

Comment: I load it in Javascript and display the model summary in the browser

Comment: @edkeveked The only difference between your configuration and my own must then be in the parsing of the model weights. I've updated the question and if you check out that link, you can find a few attempted solutions I've had. Let me know if there's anything else I could provide to clarify/help. Appreciate the help a ton!

Comment: Interesting, I'm facing the same problem. Did you try running it locally? Maybe a versioning problem? Did you try using older tf and tfjs?

Comment: @RyanCocuzzo Actually, I am loading your model using `loadLayersModel('url/of/model')`. I am not using `tf.io` handler

Answer (score 11):

Python tensorflow uses `Functional` as a class name of functional models, but tfjs use a different name for them internally.

Try changing `modelTopology.model_config.class_name` in `model.json` to `Model`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you already wrote I tried to write the model using the sequential rather than functional API:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import tensorflowjs as tfjs

# create sequential model
model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        layers.Dense(2, activation="relu", name="layer1"),
        layers.Dense(3, activation="relu", name="layer2"),
        layers.Dense(4, name="layer3"),
    ]
)
# Call model on a test input
KEY = 'sampleid'
MDL = 'mymodel'

model.compile(loss='mse',metrics='accuracy')

tfjs.converters.save_keras_model(model, MDL)
```

Loading the file as:

```
model = await tf.loadLayersModel('./mymodel/model.json');
model.summary();
```

seems to be working then. But I agree, the functional API should also work. Some more information maybe found [here](https://www.shangyexinzhi.com/article/2100748.html).