# Keras to Tensorflowjs - Unknown layer: TFOpLambda

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

I'm new to machine learning and I'm trying to get keypoint detection working in the browser.  I found this Keras tutorial:
https://keras.io/examples/vision/keypoint_detection/

I got it working in Python, and then added a line to export it to .h5:
`model.save('keypoint.h5')`

I then converted it to tfjs:
`tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=keras /keypoint.h5 /tfjs_model`

However when I try and run it in the browser like so:
`const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(‘path/to/model.json’);`

I get the following error:
`Error: Unknown layer: TFOpLambda`

Looking inside model.json I can see the following Lambda layers:

```
{"class_name": "TFOpLambda", "config": {"name": "tf.math.truediv_1", "trainable": true, "dtype": "float32", "function": "math.truediv"}, "name": "tf.math.truediv_1", "inbound_nodes": [["input_4", 0, 0, {"y": 127.5, "name": null}]]}, 
{"class_name": "TFOpLambda", "config": {"name": "tf.math.subtract_1", "trainable": true, "dtype": "float32", "function": "math.subtract"}, "name": "tf.math.subtract_1", "inbound_nodes": [["tf.math.truediv_1", 0, 0, {"y": 1.0, "name": null}]]}
```

I've read that I need to create a custom layer, but this is where I'm completely stumped.  How do I go about this? This is well beyond my current understanding but I'm keen to learn - any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50878885/unknown-layer-lambda-in-tensorflowjs-on-browser/50893452#50893452

Comment: Have you got any workaround for this yet ?